# Convert list of tuples in list of lists ( NP array )

Tags: python, numpy, awkward-array

i have a array response from a api and i got this poly:

```
poly = [(0,525),(961,525),(961,1003),(0,1003)]
```

i need to multiply each item for 0.35, them my code was it:

```
poly = ak.Array(poly) * (35/100)
```

i got a `<class 'awkward1.highlevel.Array'>` object then i changed it to a `np array`

```
poly = np.array(poly)
```

but this is converted to a wrong format

```
[(  0.  , 183.75) (336.35, 183.75) (336.35, 351.05) (  0.  , 351.05)]
```

i need that my resultant array to be this as `np.array int32`:

```
[[0, 184], [336, 184], [336, 351], [0, 351]]
```

some one can help me please?

Comment: `np.array(poly)` gives me the expected 2D array. Why do you need `ak`? Also, you can try: `ak.Array(np.array(poly) * .35)`

Comment: becouse i need that firstresult to be a awk object to my function works

Comment: yes, its a array of tutles then i need to change its proportions and convert to array of arrays

Answer (score 1):

Each of the subarrays in your `poly` array have type `numpy.void`. Directly converting the `numpy.void` into a `numpy.array` didn't work, i.e., it was not giving the shape of the array that you wanted.

Iterate over each of the `numpy.void` arrays, convert them to tuples and then convert them to `numpy.array`s, while typecasting the `float`s to `np.int32`s.

This works, as explained above:

```
import numpy as np
import awkward1.highlevel as ak

poly = [(0,525),(961,525),(961,1003),(0,1003)]
poly = ak.Array(poly) * (35/100)
poly = np.array(poly)

# Initializing a list, as NumPy was throwing some error that I haven't resolved.
poly_list = list()
for i, tup in enumerate(poly.copy()):
    # Converting to tuple and then to np.array to fix an error.
    poly_list.append(np.array(tuple(tup)))

# Converting back to a NumPy array.
poly = np.array(poly_list)

print(poly)

# Rounding and converting elements to np.int32 type
poly = poly.astype(np.int32)
```

I'm not familiar with the `awkward1` package, so this may be a hack solution. But it works.

Comment: @Jasar Orion It was throwing an error. This works now.

Answer (score 0):

i did ^^

```
import numpy as np
import awkward1 as ak




poly = [(0,525),(961,525),(961,1003),(0,1003)]
poly = ak.Array(poly) * (35/100)
print(poly)
print(type(poly))



poly = np.array(poly)
poly = [[int(i), int(j)] for i, j in poly]

print(poly)
print(type(poly))
```

i found this solution talking to a friend.